# Build only part of a Python package

Tags: python, python-packaging

So I have a python package that follow this structure:

```py
packageA:
    __init__.py
    moduleA:
        fileA.py
    moduleB:
        fileB.py
```

My problem is that `fileA.py` has pyspark dependencies while `fileB.py` doesnt so I want to be able to build packageA without moduleA to remove this dependencie. Is this possible?

Or what other solutions could I use to avoid the pyspark dependencie when using my module outside and only calling `fileB.py`?

Comment: As long as you're not importing `fileA` anywhere, the dependencies shouldn't matter, no? They should only be relevant at runtime.

Comment: Yes to what @deceze said. Plus have a look at [_setuptools_' documentation on "_Declaring “Extras” (optional features with their own dependencies)_"](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies).

Comment: @Jaime Reading your question again, I wonder if maybe you are asking how to exclude `fileA.py` from being packaged into the project's distributions (_sdist_, _wheel_, etc.). Is that what the question is about?

Answer (score 0):

Python will only build what is imported. Just make sure that you only import the file that you need, and not the entire package.

```
import packageA.moduleB.fileB
```

And not

```
import packageA
```